# Is there a continuous function $f$ such that $f( f(x))=-x^3$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Is there a continuous real valued function $f$ such that $f \circ f(x)=-x^3$.

If we set $f^0(x)=I(x)=x$, $f^1(x)=f(x)$, $f^2(x)=f\circ f(x)$, ..., then a simple argument show that $f^{2k}(x)=(-1)^kx^{3^k}$. This may help to answer the question.

Comment: As $f\circ f$ is injective, so is $f$. A continuous injective function on $\mathbb R$ is monotonic.

Comment: @ТymaGaidash $f$ need not be of that form

Answer (score 12):

No such function exists.

$g(x) = -x^3$ is a bijective (i.e. invertible, i.e. one-to-one and onto) function. As such, if $f$ is such that $g = f \circ f$, then $f$ must also be bijective. However, this means that $f$ must be monotonically increasing or monotonically decreasing. In either case, we find that $f \circ f$ must be monotonically increasing, which does not hold for $g$.